# YouTubePlayerAPI and broken videos with latest YouTube-app

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-youtube-api

We have integrated playback from YouTube in our app via YouTubePlayerAPI but recently (around two weeks ago) most of our videos are unplayable on an android device. There is nothing wrong with the videos since they are playable in our ios app, on the web (iframe) and ofcourse on YouTube.

YouTubePlayerAPI depends upon the YouTube-app and if I uninstall updates to YouTube the video is playable again. The weirdest thing is that videos that are filmed with a Nexus One Plus is playable! And that is the only device, from which a video is taken, that I've been able to play.

We upload the videos to an unlisted channel that we own and almost none of those videos are playable, if I try to play a random video from YouTube most of them work. I've seen other with the exact same problem and playing those videos doesn't work for me either and vice versa.

This is kinda a dealbreakar for many apps, including ours. It's been over two weeks since I first discovered the bug and a lot of issues has been opened to googles ticket system but they haven't answered one of them, not even acknowledged the bug.

Anyone with similar problems that have found a solution? And no, forcing users to uninstall updates to the YouTube-app is not acceptable, neither is opening the video as an YouTube-intent.

**UPDATE**

With the latest update to the YouTube-app the issue seems to be resolved and is now working as expected.